# Latest file download from FTP

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, c#-3.0, ssis-2012

In a Ftp location there are several files.

Like

File0215_27_1.zip

File0315_02_1.zip

File0315_12_1.zip

Here wannt to get the File0312_12_1.zip as it is the latest one.
How to get only the latest one using SSIS?
What should the script task code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a script task and pick some working code as a starting point. If you google for "find latest file in directory c#", you will find several examples, such as

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546159.aspx.
http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-most-recent-file-from.html.

If you still need help, please post the relevant portion of your solution, and I or someone else here will certainly help  you.